# Scipy: Integration of Hermite function with quadrature weights

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, numerical-integration

I want to integrate the product of two time- and frequency-shifted Hermite functions using scipy.integrate.quad.

However, since large order-polynomials are included, there are numerical errors occuring. Here's my Code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate
import scipy.special as sp
from math import pi


def makeFuncs():
    # Create the 0th, 4th, 8th, 12th and 16th order hermite function
    return [lambda t, n=n: np.exp(-0.5*t**2)*sp.hermite(n)(t) for n in np.arange(5)*4]

def ambgfun(funcs, i, k, tau, f):
    # Integrate f1(t)*f2(t+tau)*exp(-j2pift) over t from -inf to inf
    f1 = funcs[i]
    f2 = funcs[k]
    func = lambda t: np.real(f1(t) * f2(t+tau) * np.exp(-1j*(2*pi)*f*t))
    return scipy.integrate.quad(func, -np.inf, np.inf)

def main():
    f = makeFuncs()

    print "A00(0,0):", ambgfun(f, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    print "A01(0,0):", ambgfun(f, 0, 1, 0, 0)
    print "A34(0,0):", ambgfun(f, 3, 4, 0, 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The hermite functions are orthogonal, thus all integrals should be equal to zero. However, they are not, as the output shows:

```
A00(0,0): (1.7724538509055159, 1.4202636805184462e-08)
A01(0,0): (8.465450562766819e-16, 8.862237123626351e-09)
A34(0,0): (-10.1875, 26.317246925873935)
```

How can I make this calculation more accurate? The hermite-function from scipy contain a weights variable which should be used for Gaussian Quadrature, as given in the documentation (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html#orthogonal-polynomials). However, I have not found a hint in the docs how to use these weights.

I hope you can help :)

Thanks, Max

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the result you get is numerically as close to zero as it gets. I don' think it's really possible to get much better results if you work with floating point numbers --- you are facing a general problem in numerical integration.

Consider this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate, special
f = lambda t: np.exp(-t**2) * special.eval_hermite(12, t) * special.eval_hermite(16, t)

abs_ig, abs_err = integrate.quad(lambda t: abs(f(t)), -np.inf, np.inf)
ig, err = integrate.quad(f, -np.inf, np.inf)

print ig
# -10.203125
print abs_ig
# 2.22488114805e+15
print ig / abs_ig, err / abs_ig
# -4.58591912155e-15  1.18053770382e-14
```

The value of the integrand has therefore been computed to an accuracy comparable to the floating point epsilon. Because of the rounding error in subtracting values of a large-magnitude oscillating integrand, it's not really possible to get better results.

So how to proceed? In my experience, what you'd need to do now is to approach the problem not numerically, but analytically. Importantly, the Fourier transform of Hermite polynomials times the weight function is known, so you can work in the Fourier space all the time here.

Comment: I think it's also a question of relative error. I was working with the normalized, orthonormal hermite polynomials, and as far as I remember, my errors were much smaller in absolute terms, but I guess not in relative terms.